# Using .geojson file for SFMap Flutter

Tags: flutter, geojson, fluttermap

I am trying to use the public malaysia.geojson file for the sfmaps in my flutter app. But the file reading process throws an exception error for

```
type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'list<dynamic>' in type cast package:syncfusion_flutter_maps/src/layer/shape_layer.dart



Future<_ShapeFileData> _obtainDataSourceAndBindDataSource() async {
    shapeFileData = await _retrieveDataFromShapeFile(
        _provider, widget.source.shapeDataField, shapeFileData, isSublayer);
    if (_shouldUpdateMapDataSource) {
      minBubbleValue = null;
      maxBubbleValue = null;
      for (final MapModel model in shapeFileData.mapDataSource.values) {
        model.reset();
      }
      _bindMapsSourceIntoDataSource();
      _shouldUpdateMapDataSource = false;
    }
    return shapeFileData;
  }
```

So, the screen is not showing any map.

I tried to map the geojson file to json using the function below:

```
 Future<void> parseAndDrawAssetsOnMap() async {
    final geo = GeoJson();
    geo.processedLines.listen((GeoJsonLine line) {
      /// when a line is parsed add it to the map right away
      setState(() => lines.add(Polyline(
          strokeWidth: 2.0,
          color: Colors.blue,
          points: line.geoSerie!.toLatLng())));
    });
    geo.endSignal.listen((_) => geo.dispose());
    final data = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/malaysia.geojson');
    await geo.parse(data, verbose: true);
    //lines.addAll(geo.multiLines);
  }
```

Then, my mapsource is initialized in initstate with the

```
_mapSource = MapShapeSource.asset(
      'assets/malaysia.geojson', /* 
      shapeDataField: 'STATE_NAME', */
    );
```

The map is called using this

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: parseAndDrawAssetsOnMap(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return SfMaps(
          layers: [
            MapShapeLayer(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              source: _mapSource,
              sublayers: [
                MapPolylineLayer(
                  polylines: List<MapPolyline>.generate(
                    lines.length,
                    (int index) {
                      List<MapLatLng> mapLatLngList =
                          lines[index].points.map((value) {
                        return MapLatLng(value.latitude, value.longitude);
                      }).toList();
                      return MapPolyline(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        points: mapLatLngList,
                      );
                    },
                  ).toSet(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ));
```

The lines list contains list of polylines:
List (45 items)

```
isDotted:false
key:null
offsets:List (0 items)
points:List (43 items)
strokeCap:StrokeCap (StrokeCap.round)
strokeJoin:StrokeJoin (StrokeJoin.round)
strokeWidth:2.0
```

Points list in the item:

```
Point 1 LatLng(latitude:3.2281, longitude:101.638298)
Point 2 LatLng(latitude:3.244039, longitude:101.665592)
Point 3 LatLng(latitude:3.228271, longitude:101.672802)
Point 4 LatLng(latitude:3.222958, longitude:101.702156)
```

I wanted to show a map for Malaysia with the states bounded with lines.

The map source I am using: [https://gist.github.com/heiswayi/81a169ab39dcf749c31a]

Comment: What do you have exactly in the `lines` list after processing, can you add a one sample element's structure and data?